# Cannot connect to Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb

```
 2015-05-23 07:00:48: connect failed
 2015-05-23 07:00:49: can't connect
 Address:127.0.0.1
 PortNumber:28017(already tried 27017)
 Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1
 Authorization Skipped By You
```

I am getting this error when I try to connect using mongod. I have
   tried changing the IP and port number but nothing seems to work.

Comment: What's in your `mongodb.conf`?

Comment: bind_ip=192.168.0.1
port=27017
quiet=true
dbpath=C:\MongoDB\data\db
logpath=C:\MongoDB\data\log\mongodb.log
logappend=true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check MongoDB settings in `mongodb.conf`.

Comment `bind_ip` line

```
#Listen to local interface only. Comment out to listen on all interfaces.
#bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
```

Also check security settings

```
#auth = true
```

Update this setting and restart mongodb. It will work

Also check the port you are accessing and MongoDB port

Here is the some reference to authentication http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/authorization/